# How to make Google Place Autocomplete Controller let you keep searching even if it does not exist?

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api

How do you make Google Place Autocomplete Controller let you keep searching even if it does not exist? As of now I am limiting the use of Address Search as it clutters things up in Search Controller. I am trying to find a way to be able to keep searching even if doesn't exist within google maps. It currently gives me a, "didn't recognize that location" response. For instance, if I type in "1234 asdf", I want "1234 asdf" to be in the results controller as a stand alone and be able to click it. It obviously won't give me back a GMSPlace, but I want to give the user that option.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you found any solution as im also having this problem..

Comment: Unfortunately no...